# So what's considered acceptable in comments?

Tags: discussion, support, comments

For example, can I use 1337-speak or random unicodes? If it L00ks like english, is it acceptable????

Comment: What is the reason for it in the first place?

Comment: It generally depends on how much 1337 you use.  There is such thing as too much of a good thing.

Comment: just for laughs

Comment: 1 work the javascr1pt and google-map5 tagZ and my "I" key 1s br0ken

Comment: If you want people to actually _read_ your comments, you shouldn't make people work to do so. You will also likely attract plenty of "not-constructive" flags.

Comment: 7/-/15 15 \///-/¥ 1 \//15/-/ 7/-/3 "|\|0153 & |>01|\|71355" (1053 |23450|\| 571|_|_ 3X1573|).

Comment: m0ds 2 vs. Tina 0, well played

Answer (score 9, accepted):

|\|0, L337 $P34|< 1|\| (0////\3|\|7$ 1$ U|\|4((3P74BL3.

Comment: 0 |2|_`/???? 12345

Comment: @TinaCGHoehr What? That's not a leet dialect I recognize, for the record the English translation of my answer is "no, leet speak in comments is unacceptable"...

Comment: it's called +!/\/ /.\ 5|? 33 |<

Comment: italics: /.| /3 /= /) E /= (- /-/ / _/ /< /_ /\// /\/ () /? ()_ /2 5 + /_/ |/ \/\/ >< `/ 2

Comment: it was used back in the Commodore 64 dayZ

Comment: I would +1 if you could also submit your answer as a regex, because a regex is the answer to everything.

Comment: \/\/|-|47 0|\| 34r7|-| 1$ 7|-|1$